# displayDialogAsync messageParent not working in IE11 and outlook 2013

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-2013

Dialog opens without a problem, but the messageParent is not working

Working in

1. Outlook 2016 & Win 10
2. Outlook 2013 & Win 10
3. Outlook on web in Chrome.

The place I couldn't get to work and no value received at parent is

1. IE11 & Win 7
2. Outlook 2013 & Win 7.

Comment: Is this happening consistently?  Is it an issue only on Windows 7?

Comment: Edited question. Older question(value of displayDialogAsync) one is working as expected.

Comment: We cannot reproduce the issue on IE11, Can you confirm whether this is happening consistently? Is it an issue only on Windows 7?

Comment: Win7 may require upgrading both Windows and Office to the latest versions. What version of office are you on? (15.0.XXXX.YYYY)

Comment: Issue us consistent in IE11 + Win 7. Only isolated to windows 7

Win 7 Office version 15.0.5215.100. We can upgrade for sure, but we do not have a fallback if any user is in this older environment. Any alternatives in case this doesn't work?

Comment: Can you debug to see what may be the issue? Is it possible that you may be using some modern JS functions, that do not run in IE? (i.e. Arrow Functions)

Comment: It's clojurescript and any unsupported stuff like arrow functions show up in console(which I haven't found).

Comment: Retry this with a fresh install of win7 and do not edit any settings @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we do not support windows 7 anymore. Support for Windows 7 ended on January 14, 2020. If someone is still using Windows 7, the PC may become more vulnerable to security risks.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-windows-7-support